# How to freeze particulars parameters of RNN restricting from training using keras-python

Tags: python, keras, freeze, recurrent-neural-network

How do I freeze particular parameters in a layer in a RNN. Here I would like to check if a RNN is noise resistant. So I add gaussian noise to some weights(like few weights of input-to-hidden parameter matrix) and I need to freeze them, so that they could not be trained. (So not the whole input-to-hidden parameter matrix but only few of them must be frozen).How to do this with keras-python?

Comment: "certain cells in a layer"? An RNN layer in Keras only has 1 cell that is repeatedly applied. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is the question clear now nuric?